# ¿Cómo cerrar modal Angular 7 + Boostrap 4?

Tags: javascript, modal, angular7

Estoy utilizando Angular 7 + Boostrap 4 y estoy abriendo un modal el cual está llamando a un componente a parte para ser mostrado en el cuerpo del modal. El contenido que se está llamando por medio de este componente es un formulario, pero al dar click en cancelar o guardar no consigo cerrar el modal.

Sería de gran ayuda si alguien puede colaborarme con esto.

*Esta es la imagen del modal que estoy abriendo llamando otro componente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*Este sería el formulario que hay en el componente llamado desde el modal:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*Método que está en el **component.ts** de este formulario donde la variable valdría:

modal: NgbModalRef;

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*Se añade código html del botón que abre el modal:

```
<button type="button" class="btn-shadow d-inline-flex align-items-center btn btn-primary" (click)="openModal(createNewEvent)">
    <i class="fa fa-plus mr-2" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    Crear Evento
  </button>
```

*Se añade código html donde se abre el modal:

```html
<ng-template #createNewEvent  let-modal="dismiss">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-basic-title">Nuevo evento</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="modal('Close')">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <app-add-new-evento-form (eventoNewRegistry)="eventoNewRegistry($event)"></app-add-new-evento-form>
</ng-template>
```

*Se añade el componente (formulario) que abre el modal:

```js
import {Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators} from "@angular/forms"; //Construir,grupo, validar formulario
import {NgbModalRef, ModalDismissReasons, NgbDateStruct} from "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-new-evento-form',
  templateUrl: './add-new-evento-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-new-evento-form.component.sass']
})
export class AddNewEventoFormComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() dismiss;
  @Output() eventoNewRegistry: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter(); //Salida de campos del formulario
  eventoNewRegistryForm: FormGroup; //Formulario
  modal: NgbModalRef;
  modelFechaEnd: NgbDateStruct;
  modelFechaInit: NgbDateStruct;
  fechaInicial: number;
  fechaFinal: number;

  constructor(public fb: FormBuilder) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    /**
     * @desc Se crea y se valida el formulario
     */
    this.eventoNewRegistryForm = this.fb.group({
      titulo: ['', Validators.required],
      info: ['', Validators.required],
      fechaInicio: ['', Validators.required],
      fechaFin: ['', Validators.required],
      valor: ['', Validators.required],
      cupos: ['', Validators.required],
      categoria: ['', Validators.required],
      clasificacion: ['', Validators.required],
    });
  }

  closeModal() {
    this.modal.close();
  }

  onSubmit(form, valid: boolean) {
    if (valid) {
      //Se obtiene la fecha inicial y se convierte a milisegundos
      this.fechaInicial = new Date(
        form.fechaInicio.year,
        form.fechaInicio.month - 1,
        form.fechaInicio.day
      ).getTime();

      //Se obtiene la fecha final y se convierte a milisegundos
      this.fechaFinal = new Date(
        form.fechaInicio.year,
        form.fechaInicio.month - 1,
        form.fechaInicio.day
      ).getTime();

      //Se crea formulario para enviar
      let formulario = {
        titulo: form.titulo,
        info: form.info,
        valor: form.valor,
        cupos: form.cupos,
        categoria: form.categoria,
        clasificacion: form.clasificacion,
        fechaInicio: this.fechaInicial,
        fechaFin: this.fechaFinal
      };
      this.eventoNewRegistry.emit(formulario);
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<form novalidate [formGroup]="eventoNewRegistryForm" class="needs-validation"
      (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(eventoNewRegistryForm.value, eventoNewRegistryForm.valid)">

  <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="alert alert-warning">
      <span>Mediante esta acción podrá crear un nuevo evento.</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="alignColums">
    <!--PRIMERA COLUMNA-->
    <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7">

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-4">Titulo:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input formControlName="titulo" type="text" class="form-control" id="titulo"
                 placeholder="Nombre Evento"
                 required>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-4">Información:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
         <textarea rows="1" formControlName="info" type="text" class="form-control" id="info"
                   placeholder="Información Evento"
                   required style="overflow: hidden; height: 41px; margin-top: 0px;"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-4">Fecha Incio:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input class="form-control" name="fechaInicio" formControlName="fechaInicio" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"
                   [(ngModel)]="modelFechaInit"
                   ngbDatepicker #fechaInicio="ngbDatepicker">
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="fechaInicio.toggle()" type="button">
                <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-4">Categoría:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input formControlName="categoria" type="text" class="form-control" id="categoria"
                 placeholder="Categoria Evento"
                 required>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <!--SEGUNDA COLUMNA-->
    <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7">

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-4" for="valor">Valor:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input formControlName="valor" type="text" class="form-control" id="valor"
                 placeholder="Valor Evento"
                 required>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-4" for="cupos">Cupos:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input formControlName="cupos" type="number" class="form-control" id="cupos"
                 placeholder="Cupos Evento"
                 required>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-4">Fecha Final:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input class="form-control" name="fechaFin" formControlName="fechaFin" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"
                   [(ngModel)]="modelFechaEnd"
                   ngbDatepicker #fechaFin="ngbDatepicker">
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="fechaFin.toggle()" type="button">
                <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-4">Clasificación:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <select class="form-control" formControlName="clasificacion" type="text" placeholder="Clasificación Evento"
                  required>
            <option disabled selected>*Elija una clasificación</option>
            <option value="ACTIVIDAD">Actividad</option>
            <option value="EVENTO">Evento</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary" aria-label="Close" (click)="closeModal()" type="button">Cancelar</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" [disabled]="eventoNewRegistryForm.invalid">Guardar</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Andrés, seria bueno que colocaras el código en forma de texto en vez de imagen.

Comment: Hola, ya postee el codigo. gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
import {Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators} from "@angular/forms"; //Construir,grupo, validar formulario
import {NgbModalRef, ModalDismissReasons, NgbDateStruct} from "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap";


@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-new-evento-form',
  templateUrl: './add-new-evento-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-new-evento-form.component.sass']
})
export class AddNewEventoFormComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() dismiss;
  @Output() eventoNewRegistry: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter(); //Salida de campos del formulario
  eventoNewRegistryForm: FormGroup; //Formulario
  modal: NgbModalRef;
  modelFechaEnd: NgbDateStruct;
  modelFechaInit: NgbDateStruct;
  fechaInicial: number;
  fechaFinal: number;

  constructor(public fb: FormBuilder) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    /**
     * @desc Se crea y se valida el formulario
     */
    this.eventoNewRegistryForm = this.fb.group({
      titulo: ['', Validators.required],
      info: ['', Validators.required],
      fechaInicio: ['', Validators.required],
      fechaFin: ['', Validators.required],
      valor: ['', Validators.required],
      cupos: ['', Validators.required],
      categoria: ['', Validators.required],
      clasificacion: ['', Validators.required],
    });
  }

  closeModal() {
    this.modal.close();
  }

  onSubmit(form, valid: boolean) {
    if (valid) {
      //Se obtiene la fecha inicial y se convierte a milisegundos
      this.fechaInicial = new Date(
        form.fechaInicio.year,
        form.fechaInicio.month - 1,
        form.fechaInicio.day
      ).getTime();

      //Se obtiene la fecha final y se convierte a milisegundos
      this.fechaFinal = new Date(
        form.fechaInicio.year,
        form.fechaInicio.month - 1,
        form.fechaInicio.day
      ).getTime();

      //Se crea formulario para enviar
      let formulario = {
        titulo: form.titulo,
        info: form.info,
        valor: form.valor,
        cupos: form.cupos,
        categoria: form.categoria,
        clasificacion: form.clasificacion,
        fechaInicio: this.fechaInicial,
        fechaFin: this.fechaFinal
      };
      this.eventoNewRegistry.emit(formulario);
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<form novalidate [formGroup]="eventoNewRegistryForm" class="needs-validation"
      (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(eventoNewRegistryForm.value, eventoNewRegistryForm.valid)">

  <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="alert alert-warning">
      <span>Mediante esta acción podrá crear un nuevo evento.</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="alignColums">
    <!--PRIMERA COLUMNA-->
    <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7">

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-4">Titulo:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input formControlName="titulo" type="text" class="form-control" id="titulo"
                 placeholder="Nombre Evento"
                 required>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-4">Información:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
         <textarea rows="1" formControlName="info" type="text" class="form-control" id="info"
                   placeholder="Información Evento"
                   required style="overflow: hidden; height: 41px; margin-top: 0px;"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-4">Fecha Incio:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input class="form-control" name="fechaInicio" formControlName="fechaInicio" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"
                   [(ngModel)]="modelFechaInit"
                   ngbDatepicker #fechaInicio="ngbDatepicker">
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="fechaInicio.toggle()" type="button">
                <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-4">Categoría:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input formControlName="categoria" type="text" class="form-control" id="categoria"
                 placeholder="Categoria Evento"
                 required>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <!--SEGUNDA COLUMNA-->
    <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7">

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-4" for="valor">Valor:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input formControlName="valor" type="text" class="form-control" id="valor"
                 placeholder="Valor Evento"
                 required>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-4" for="cupos">Cupos:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input formControlName="cupos" type="number" class="form-control" id="cupos"
                 placeholder="Cupos Evento"
                 required>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-4">Fecha Final:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input class="form-control" name="fechaFin" formControlName="fechaFin" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"
                   [(ngModel)]="modelFechaEnd"
                   ngbDatepicker #fechaFin="ngbDatepicker">
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="fechaFin.toggle()" type="button">
                <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-4">Clasificación:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <select class="form-control" formControlName="clasificacion" type="text" placeholder="Clasificación Evento"
                  required>
            <option disabled selected>*Elija una clasificación</option>
            <option value="ACTIVIDAD">Actividad</option>
            <option value="EVENTO">Evento</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary" aria-label="Close" (click)="closeModal()" type="button">Cancelar</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" [disabled]="eventoNewRegistryForm.invalid">Guardar</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

***Econtre la respuesta despues de varios intentos y la dejare aca por si depronto a alguien le pasa

-Lo que hice fue crear un emiter desde el formulario para tratarlo al llegar al componente padre y asi poder cerrar la modal

```js
  @Output() modal: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();  //Salida de evento para cerrar modal


 /**
   * @name closeModal
   * @desc Metodo que emite un evento al componente padre para cerrar la modal
   */
  closeModal() {
    this.modal.emit('close');
  }
```

- En el componente padre queda así

```html
<ng-template #createNewEvent  let-modal="dismiss">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-basic-title">Nuevo evento</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="modal('Close')">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <app-add-new-evento-form (eventoNewRegistry)="eventoNewRegistry($event)" (modal)="modal('Close')" ></app-add-new-evento-form>
</ng-template>
```